# AngularJS will not render scope inside img tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is AngularJS not rendering one of my scope variables correct when it placed inside an `<img src=`

For example: this renders without any problems:

```
{{badge.image}}
```

**outputs = /images/test.png**

but this does not:

```
 <img src='{{badge.image}}' />
```

**outputs = %7B%7Bbadge.image%7D%7D**

whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use

```
<img ng-src='{{badge.image}}' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead:

```
<img ng-src="{{badge.image}}" />
```